# Animate SVG element transform (rotate & scale) in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a animation (`transform` + `transition`) of an SVG element (an arrow) spinning around a circle (sometimes with scale). It works in latest Chrome, Opera, Firefox (safari I havent tested but I presume it works there as well). But it doesn't work in IE, as the transform for the SVG element there needs to be set with the `transform` attribute. So I added a line to my script that applies the same transform to the attribute, but the animation doesn't happen, it just "skips" to the new position.

I've made a JSfiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/rv28ezfw/3/
In IE, the rotation/scale don't get animated, and I need to find a way to fix that.

Is there a plugin or some function that will take care of the animation in IE for me? Preferably without adjusting the functionality that already works everywhere else..

I was looking at a [jQuery SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) and CSS Tricks.com have a [demo](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/) (at the very bottom of the article) that works in IE as well, but I was hope for something more simple. But if You recommend one or the other Ill go with it.

Comment: Wich version of IE do you target ? http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: I would say 11+. And the page says it is supported in IE 11. But It doesn't work for me. It says im on IE 11.0.9600.18376. So how come it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out why it wasn't working in IE11. Instead, here's a workaround:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  // Changed to make demo smoother.
  $('#container').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

```css
#container {
  /* Resized so it looks better in snippet */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  /* So you can see what's going on */
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Changed to make it transparent, otherwise you may cover other elements */
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  /* So any elements underneath can still receive events */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* Moved here from svg */
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
/* Added */
#container.rotated {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#btn {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

.cls-1 {
  fill: #2bffaa;
}

.cls-2 {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.cls-3 {
  fill: #f2f2f2;
}

.cls-4 {
  fill: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">GO</div>
<div id="container">
  <svg id="scroller" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
    <title>demo</title>
    <path id="scroller__outer" class="cls-1" d="M240,147a92.93,92.93,0,0,0-28.29,4.39l5.14,12A80.1,80.1,0,1,1,179.23,188L132.31,226.4c13.11,3.06,15.18,4.06,15.18,4.06S147,236.78,147,240A93,93,0,1,0,240,147Z" />
    <path id="scroller__inner" class="cls-2" d="M240,158a84.78,84.78,0,0,0-23.82,3.86l1.76,4.13,6.59,15,0.68,1.44A59.46,59.46,0,1,1,190.56,207l-0.92-1.44-9.17-15.41L179.23,188c-12,14-21.22,32.14-21.22,52,0,44.18,37.82,82,82,82s82-37.82,82-82S284.18,158,240,158Z"
    />
    <circle id="scroll__inner__circle" class="cls-3" cx="240" cy="240" r="51.5" />
    <path id="scroll__inner__outline" class="cls-4" d="M240,179a61,61,0,1,0,61,61A61,61,0,0,0,240,179Zm0,117a56,56,0,1,1,56-56A56,56,0,0,1,240,296Z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Basically, I rotate `#container` instead of the SVG itself. Then, it was a matter of moving the `transform`s onto `#container`.

Because we're rotating a `div`, the corners can overlap elements underneath. In this demo, I made it transparent but outlined the borders so you could see them. Because of `pointer-events: none`, the user won't be prevented from clicking on the "GO" button if a corner of the `div` overlaps it.

You could also change your SVG a little so there's not so much white space around the icon.